# Responding with Text on Calling Event in Skype Bot

Tags: c#, bots, skype, botframework

I am trying to respond to a Skype bot calling event with a text message. Is there a direct way to do that?

For instance I have the following event for receiving a new call:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> ProcessIncomingCallAsync()
    {
        return await CallingConversation.SendAsync(Request, CallRequestType.IncomingCall);
    }
```

What I would like to do is to handle the event normally and send a text reply to the client like what I am doing with in this messaging event:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody]Activity activity)
    {
        if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
        {
            Activity reply = activity.CreateReply($"You sent {activity.Text} which was {length} characters");
            await connector.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(reply);
        }

        var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        return response;
    }
```

I expect that the bot framework will not be able to handle that because it transfers the request and response messages over a specific channel which is either calling or messaging.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Are you still looking into this?

Comment: Not really, but it would be nice to know if there is a way to do that.